# Difference between Template Helper and Template Variable in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, handlebars.js

What is the difference between using a Template Helper and a Template Variable (incorrect term?)? When do you decide which to use?

In the example below, both `Template.apple.price` function and the `quantity` function in `Template.apple.helpers` appear to do the same thing.

```
<template name="apple">
    {{price}}
    {{quantity}}
</template>



Template.apple.price = function() {
    return 20;
}

Template.apple.helpers({
    'quantity': function() {
        return 100;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing, as explained in [this section of the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_helpers). The only difference that the second way allows you to use more keywords. For example, you can't do this:

```
Template.foo.events = function() { /*...*/ };
```

But you can do this:

```
Template.foo.helpers({
    "events": function() { /*...*/ }
});
```

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: You can't use reserved keywords as keys in the first example. Though you wouldn't want to use them in the second, either.